# How to split 4 columns, one row into 2 columns, two rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using `SSRS 2008R2` and `SSMS 2008R2` and I am trying to split 4 columns, one row into two rows, 2 columns.  How can I do this?

Here is some sample data:

```
create table #foo
(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int)
insert #foo values(1,2,3,4)
insert #foo values(5,6,7,8)
insert #foo values(9,10,11,12)
select * from #foo
```

But I want to transform this data to look like this:

```
create table #goo (col1 int, col2 int)
insert #goo values(1,2)
insert #goo values(3,4)
insert #goo values(5,6)
insert #goo values(7,8)
insert #goo values(9,10)
insert #goo values(11,12)
select * from #goo
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As simple as:

```
create table #foo(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int);
insert #foo values(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8),(9,10,11,12);

SELECT col1, col2 
FROM #foo
UNION ALL 
SELECT col3, col4
FROM #foo;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/412121)**</kbd>

First 2 columns `UNION ALL` with 3rd and 4th columns.

If you need to store in #goo use:

```
SELECT col1, col2
INTO #goo 
FROM #foo
UNION ALL 
SELECT col3, col4
FROM #foo;

SELECT * FROM #goo;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I knew this was simple

Answer (score 1):

I imagine it would look something like this

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", col1, col2) FROM #foo UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", col3, col4) FROM #foo;
```

Breakdown

`concat_ws` - Combines two columns with a word separator. In this case a space.

`Union All` - Merges with another selector to create multiple rows.

SQLFiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca24df/3/0

Comment: Click `LINK` below resultset (near show execution plan). Then the url will get new value.